# return key doesn't work when i use regex in QT C++

Tags: c++, regex, qt, qlineedit

Hey guys I'm trying to use regex on line edit in QT but when I use my regex one function that do something when I enter the return key on keyboard doesn't work any more!

This is my regex on line edit:

```
QRegularExpression r("[0-9\\.\\+\\-\\=\\/\\*\n]{100}");
ui->lineEdit->setValidator(new QRegularExpressionValidator (r,this));
```

And this is my function test:

```
void MainWindow::on_lineEdit_returnPressed()
{
    on_pushButton_14_clicked();
}
```

I also try my regex without "\n" but doesn't change any thing. When I comment the regex my function works correctly.

So any solution?

Comment: Random guess: the return key sends a `\r` character that your regex does not allow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regex needs to support a pattern of length one, thus, `{100}` quantifier should be replaced with `{1,100}` or even `{0,100}`.

Besides, you may also add `\r` (carriage return) char to the character set, and remove unnecessary escapes:

```cpp
QRegularExpression r("^[0-9.+=/*\n\r-]{1,100}$");
```

I added `^` and `$` anchors to make sure the regex only matches the whole string (here, line).